# How to change the table row background color while the conditions fails?

Tags: wicket

I am merging three coloumns and showing the merged values in the 4th column, am appliying some rules for merge operation. In some case that rules will bring up null value and display it in any row in the 4th column, i want to highlight the null row alone in RED color.

Like listed below.

Value1

Value2

NULL(Red color)

Value 4

please help me on this, Am working in wicket framework.

Comment: It will be much easier to answer this clearly if you supply some code as a base to work from.

Comment: Plesse, add code snippet and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AttributeModifier.replace("class", IModel<?>)`. Put a string in the model of the css tag you have to make it red. For example `td.redbox {backgroundcolor:red}` with `AttributeModifier.replace("class", Model.of("redbox"));`.

ps.
You need to supply more code next time. If you ask a unclear question, you'll get an unclear answer.

Comment: You can use the AttributeModifier on you textfield and then add this css `input[class=redbox] {backgroundcolor:red}`. Do `compDraft.add(AttributeModifier.replace("class", Model.of("redbox")));`

Comment: actually the built code structure is very complicated i couldn't able to post that here. Am merging there coloumns say version1,version2,version3 and displaying it in a final column say latest version, in that final column i need to highlight the failre row in red color. 

this is the componenet am using.

String Draft;
compDraft= new TextField("draft", new PropertyModel<String>(this,
    "draft"));

Html tag for the componenet

<td><input class="draft" style="font-family: Segoe UI;border:0px;background-color:#FAFFBD;" type="text" wicket:id="draft"/><td>